# How to run a script when accessing a specific path?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, hook

I have some path I have to access, which is the result of mounting.

I would like the mounting to be automatic, via a script, and I want that script to run just before an error is thrown from not being able to access the path.

For example, assume the script is

```
echo scripting!
mkdir -p /non_existing_path
```

and I want it to run when trying to access (in any way) to the path `/non_existing_path`.

So when I do for example

```
cd /non_existing_path
```

or

```
touch /non_existing_path/my_file.txt
```

It would always succeed, with the output `scripting!`. In reality, the script would be more elaborated than that.

---

Is this possible at all?

Comment: `access (in any way)` you would have to basically modify linux kernel to trap `open` syscall, But why you would want that? `touch` "accesses" _many_ other paths  - see `strace touch` - `/etc/ld.so.cache` `/usr/lib/libc.so.6` `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` `/usr/share/locale/locale.alias` `/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache` you wouldn't want to create them. I suggest to write your own wrappers around _specific_ commands that use arguments.

Comment: @KamilCuk I may have misexplained. I would NOT want to create them. I want the script to run only upon accessing a SPECIFIC path. I think of it as connecting a hook or listener on that path.

Comment: You could create a fuse filesystem that automatically creates the paths in that mountpoint.

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you elaborate please? I don't know what a fuse filesystem is or how to do that.

Comment: You question, as of now, is _very broad_. How is "access" defined? "Who", what set of programs, are meant to be affected?  I do not know if: you want to execute a specific script when _any_ process executes `open` syscall on specific path. Or maybe you want only to create the directory when _any_ proces executes `open` syscall. Or do you care about syscalls at all? Is it meant to be specific to `cd` and `touch` commands only and no other? If others, which ones? You tagged bash - you want that to happen _only_ in bash shell? `is the result of mounting.` What mounting? Mounting of what?

Comment: As for fuse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace  https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/index.html

Comment: @KamilCuk I was not aware there was a difference. Let's say only `cd`, `mount` and `touch`, and I will handle other commands just the same. By "access" I mean attempting to make use of the path in a linux built-in command (such as the ones above).

Comment: @KamilCuk About from which process - doesn't matter, as I will only ever use it from a synchronous command line

Comment: @KamilCuk I am mounting some storage drive. Again, I was not aware this makes any difference. Can you explain what information is missing?

Comment: I want the script that is run to be a bash script. I don't mind it being Python, or anything else. The point of the question is creating the hook.

Comment: So why not just `cd() { ./your_script "$@"; builtin cd "$@"; }` from your shell? and then `./your_script` would have to parse arguments and handle what to do. `Let's say only cd, mount and touch, and I will handle other commands just the same` So it is specific to limited set of commands? So if I write a C program that opens a directory in that path, should it also be affected or not (this is the important case)? It really depends on what you mean by "access (in any way)". Does `lstat()` syscall counts as access or only `cd /dir` only counts as access?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, the important case is that 3rd parties (such as a new C program, command line, or other scripts) that would call for example `cd` should also be affected, and a call by them to `cd` as they normally would, should invoke the hooked script beforehand.

Comment: Then I believe this is unrelated to [bash], is it? And to [command-line]?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand.

- Do you want the script to run even if the path is not accessible?
- Do you want the script to run only if the path is not accessible?
- Is the script supposed to mount the "not accessible" path?

In any case, I think you should just use an `if else` [statement](https://linuxhint.com/bash_if_else_examples/)

The script would look like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "/non_existing_path" ]
then
    bash $1
else
    bash $1
    mkdir -p /non_existing_path
fi
```

Lets assume this script's name is "myScript.sh" and the external script's name is "extScript.sh". You would call:
`bash myScript.sh /home/user/extScript.sh`

This script will check if path exist.
If yes, execute `bash /home/user/extScript.sh`
If no, execute `bash /home/user/extScript.sh` and `mkdir...`

Again, I'm not sure to get you goal, but you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Running from an external script defeats the purpose. I want what you suggested to happen REGARDLESS OF THE CALLING SCRIPT. I want to attach a hook to the file path.

Comment: Then you just have to call the external script as variable. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, the important case is that 3rd parties (such as a new C program, command line, or other scripts) that would call for example cd should also be affected, and a call by them to cd as they normally would, should invoke the hooked script beforehand.

Out of kernel:

Write a fuse filesystem that would mount on top of other filesystem, that would upon `open()` syscall run `fork()+execve()` a custom script.

In kernel:

Write kernel filesystem that would expose `/proc/some/interface` and would create a filesystem "on-top" of underlying existing handle. Such kernel module would execute a special command upon `open()` system call and forward all others. In `open()` system call, the kernel would write some data to `/proc/some/interface` and wait for an answer. After receiving the answer, `open()` syscall would continue.

Write a user-space demon that would for example `poll()` on events on a `/proc/some/interface` waiting for events, then `read()` the events, parse them and execute custom script. Then after the script completion, it would write to `/proc/some/interface` on the same file descriptor to notify the kernel module that the operation has compleated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use autofs?

```
autofs is a program for automatically mounting directories on an as-needed basis.
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs